# SwiftUI: Listening for changes in my data to have other views use the updated data

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have my main view decoding JSON and then enumerating that JSON to show a list of towns that you can toggle the `favorite` field on them.
I want to have a separate view to display only the towns that are `favorited` and I suspect I'd want to listen for changes to `countries` using ObservableObject and @Published. I just don't know how to implement this since I am not using any `class` objects.

**Towns.json**

```
[
    {
      "display_name": "California",
      "favorite": false,
    },
    {
      "display_name": "Colorado",
      "favorite": false,
    }

]
```

**Town.swift**

```
struct Town: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {image}
    let display_name: String
    var favorite: Bool
}
```

**MainView.swift**

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var towns : [Town] = Bundle.main.decode("Towns.json")

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(towns.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,town) in
            LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                HStack {
                    Text(town.display_name)
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        towns[index].favorite.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        if town.favorite {
                            Image(systemName: "flame").foregroundColor(.red)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "flame.fill").foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you could use a ObservableObject, but if you want to display just the "favorite" towns in another view, I would simply do this:

```
struct Town: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString // for testing
    let display_name: String
    var favorite: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSecondView = false
    // @State var towns: [Town] = Bundle.main.decode("Towns.json")
    // for testing
    @State var towns: [Town] = [Town(display_name: "California", favorite: false),
                               Town(display_name: "Colorado", favorite: false)]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button ("Show SecondView") { showSecondView.toggle() }
            
            ForEach(Array(towns.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,town) in
                LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(town.display_name)
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            towns[index].favorite.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            if town.favorite {
                                Image(systemName: "flame").foregroundColor(.red)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "flame.fill").foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
            SecondTownView(towns: $towns)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondTownView: View {
    @Binding var towns: [Town]
    var body: some View {
        // here filter the towns on favorite
        ForEach(Array(towns.filter{$0.favorite}.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,town) in
            LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(town.display_name)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```